# ag grid does not react to scroll in infinite scrolling pagination

Tags: pagination, ag-grid

I have server side pagination. I've created a simple back-end service to mimic it. See https://gitlab.com/sunnyatticsoftware/sasw-community/sasw-pagination-tester

The back-end can be run as a docker container on port 5000 (or any other)  with

```
docker run -p 5000:8080 registry.gitlab.com/sunnyatticsoftware/sasw-community/sasw-pagination-tester:latest
```

This is gonna allow to query items (i.e: tickets in this case) with pagination filtering. See its swagger http://localhost:5000/swagger for more info and/or to interact with the sample.

It works in a pretty standard way.

To retrieve the first page with pagination size of 5 items per page:

```
GET http://localhost:5000/api/tickets?Page=1&Count=5
```

To retrieve the second page with pagination size of 5 items per page:

```
GET http://localhost:5000/api/tickets?Page=2&Count=10
```

etcetera.

The result would have enough information to be able to draw any table on a UI with pagination links and info about total items and total pages:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "id": "00000001-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "channel": "chat",
      "subject": "one"
    },
    {
      "id": "00000002-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "channel": "email",
      "subject": "two"
    },
    {
      "id": "00000003-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "channel": "email",
      "subject": "three"
    },
    {
      "id": "00000004-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "channel": "phone",
      "subject": "four"
    },
    {
      "id": "00000005-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "channel": "chat",
      "subject": "five"
    }
  ],
  "pageNumber": 1,
  "pageSize": 5,
  "totalPages": 7,
  "totalCount": 32
}
```

**THE PROBLEM**
I want to use agGrid for the UI, with infinite scrolling, but I am struggling with the examples, as they all seem to have a previous fetch of a json that later is sliced to show results while scrolling. It would've been useful to have a sample with real integration, but in theory that shouldn't be a problem.

I cannot have the infinite scroll working. For whatever reason, it loads the first items but then the agGrid does not trigger the `getRows` anymore, and I don't know what am I missing.

I would like to have a simple infinite scrolling example working with the server-side pagination already in place. The following html/js won't send a second request to the server after scrolling.

The `index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>JavaScript example</title>
        <meta charSet="UTF-8"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
        <style media="only screen">
            html, body {
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
            }

            html {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                padding: 0;
                overflow: auto;
            }

            body {
                padding: 1rem;
                overflow: auto;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="myGrid" style="height: 100%" class="ag-theme-alpine-dark">
        </div>
        <script>var __basePath = './';</script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/ag-grid-enterprise@28.1.3/dist/ag-grid-enterprise.min.js">
        </script>
        <script src="main.js">
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and the `main.js`

```
(() => {

  const gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: [
      { valueGetter: 'node.rowIndex', maxWidth: 100 },
      { field: 'id', minWidth: 150 },
      { field: 'channel', minWidth: 150 },
      { field: 'subject', minWidth: 400 }
    ],
  
    defaultColDef: {
      flex: 1,
      minWidth: 80,
    },
  
    rowModelType: 'serverSide',
    serverSideInfiniteScroll: true,
    cacheBlockSize: 10,
    maxBlocksInCache: 2,
    rowBuffer: 0,
    //blockLoadDebounceMillis: 1000,
    debug: true,
  };
  

  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var gridDiv = document.querySelector('#myGrid');
    new agGrid.Grid(gridDiv, gridOptions);
    var datasource = createDataSource();
    gridOptions.api.setServerSideDatasource(datasource);
  });

  function createDataSource() {
    return {
      //rowCount: undefined,
      getRows: (params) => {
        console.log(`params start row:${params.startRow}, params end row: ${params.endRow}`);

        var pagination = getPagination(params.startRow, params.endRow);

        console.log(`asking for page ${pagination.page} and count ${pagination.count}`);

        // send new request
        fetch(`http://localhost:5000/api/tickets?page=${pagination.page}&count=${pagination.count}`)
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then(data => {
            console.log("data received");
            console.log(data);
            console.log(params);

            params.success({
              rowData: data.items,
              rowCount: pagination.page * pagination.count,
            });

            //gridOptions.api.setRowCount(data.totalCount);
          });
      },
    };
  }

  function getPagination(startRow, endRow){
    let pagination = {
      page: 1,
      count: 10
    };

    if(startRow && endRow){
      let size = endRow - startRow;
      let page = Math.ceil(startRow / size);
      pagination = {
        page: page,
        count: size
      };
    }

    return pagination;
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The problem was in the row count itself (probably) as it needs to be set to the total existing count of items that exist in back-end, so that the grid knows that needs more.

Here's a possible solution.

**For ag-grid Enterprise**

```
(() => {

  const gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: [
      { valueGetter: 'node.rowIndex', maxWidth: 100 },
      { field: 'id', minWidth: 150 },
      { field: 'channel', minWidth: 150 },
      { field: 'subject', minWidth: 400 }
    ],
  
    defaultColDef: {
      flex: 1,
      minWidth: 80,
    },
  
    rowModelType: 'serverSide',
    serverSideInfiniteScroll: true,
    cacheBlockSize: 10, //this is the count (page size)
    maxBlocksInCache: 2,
    rowBuffer: 0,
    debug: false
  };
  

  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var gridDiv = document.querySelector('#myGrid');
    new agGrid.Grid(gridDiv, gridOptions);
    var datasource = createDataSource();
    gridOptions.api.setServerSideDatasource(datasource);
  });

  function createDataSource() {
    return {
      getRows: (params) => {
        let count = params.request.endRow - params.request.startRow; // or the cacheBlockSize
        let page = Math.ceil(params.request.endRow / count);

        console.log(`asking for page ${page} and count ${count}`);

        fetch(`http://localhost:5000/api/tickets?page=${page}&count=${count}`)
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then(data => {

            params.success({
              rowData: data.items,
              rowCount: data.totalCount,
            });
          });
      },
    };
  }

})();
```

**For ag-grid Community**
A few things are different,

- obviously the ag-grid library is a different one.
- the row model type is `infinite`
- the grid options api method to set datasource is called `setDatasource`
- there is no object `response` within the injected getRows parameter, so the `startRow` and `endRow` are retrieved directly from the params object.

at `index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>JavaScript example</title>
        <meta charSet="UTF-8"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
        <style media="only screen">
            html, body {
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
            }

            html {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                padding: 0;
                overflow: auto;
            }

            body {
                padding: 1rem;
                overflow: auto;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="myGrid" style="height: 100%" class="ag-theme-alpine-dark">
        </div>
        <script>var __basePath = './';</script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/ag-grid-community/dist/ag-grid-community.min.js">
        </script>
        <script src="main.js">
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

at `main.js`

```
(() => {

  const gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: [
      { valueGetter: 'node.rowIndex', maxWidth: 100 },
      { field: 'id', minWidth: 150 },
      { field: 'channel', minWidth: 150 },
      { field: 'subject', minWidth: 400 }
    ],
  
    defaultColDef: {
      flex: 1,
      minWidth: 80,
    },
  
    rowModelType: 'infinite',
    cacheBlockSize: 10, //this is the count (page size)
    maxBlocksInCache: 2,
    rowBuffer: 0,
    debug: false
  };
  

  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var gridDiv = document.querySelector('#myGrid');
    new agGrid.Grid(gridDiv, gridOptions);
    var datasource = createDataSource();
    gridOptions.api.setDatasource(datasource);
  });

  function createDataSource() {
    return {
      getRows: (params) => {
        console.log(params);
        let count = params.endRow - params.startRow; // or the cacheBlockSize
        let page = Math.ceil(params.endRow / count);

        console.log(`asking for page ${page} and count ${count}`);

        fetch(`http://localhost:5000/api/tickets?page=${page}&count=${count}`) // any additional filter must be set on that url as query params
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then(data => {

            params.successCallback(data.items, data.totalCount);
          });
      },
    };
  }

})();
```